# After AJAX callback, onblur goes back to original (or updated) field

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, callback

I have an AJAX callback:

HTML:

```
<a onCLick="loadXMLDoc(id1,id2)">(Add)</a>
```

This calls an AJAX function that calls back a basic html input field in place of the above "(Add)"

onChange in this input field performs another AJAX callback that loads user input into a database.

What I am trying to do is once the field is filled out (or not filled out) and the field is blurred, it either goes back to the original or the newly updated value (but not any longer an input field).

I have searched around for a while and have come up with nothing. I am also new to javascript and AJAX. If it helps, I am using PHP mainly in this application.

Thanks

**ADDITION**

This is what I am trying to achieve:

- The page lists different entries in table format.
- There is a specific field that either has an id (stored in the database), or if field is null (in database) that field will display a button to add the id.
- When pressed, the button calls a function which calls back an input field, the this replaces the previous "add" button. The AJAX callback places the input field in place of the "add" button.
- **This is where I need the help:** After the user inputs the ID (or decides not to) and once the field no longer has focus, it changes from an input field back to what it was or the newly enter id. I am trying to do all this **without** refreshing the page.

Comment: Sorry, but it is just not clear to me what you want help with.  Can you list a series of steps that describe exactly what you want to happen and then describe where you need help?

Comment: @jfriend00 I listed this out, hope it is clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't follow exactly, but hopefully this will show you a means of creating/changing DOM elements in response to events like you've mentioned:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").on("blur", ".name", function(e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (!val) {
            $(this).closest(".row").html("<button class='add'>Add</button>");
        } else {
            $(this).closest(".row").html("<span class='label'>Name: </span><span>" + val + "</span>");
        }
    });

    $("#container").on("click", ".add", function(e) {
        var html = "<span class='label'>New Name: </span><input class='name' type='text' />";
        var row = $(this).closest(".row").html(html);
        row.find("input").focus();
    });

});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/01ajd0y9/